# updating old column values on insert

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table like this

```
|  id_1  |  id_2  |  new  |
|  1     |  1     |  1    |
|  1     |  2     |  1    |
|  1     |  3     |  1    |
```

now i want to add more rows and update old rows having `unique key` on `[id_1, id_2]` so i do this queries

```
UPDATE table
SET new = 0
WHERE id_1 = 1
---
INSERT INTO table (id_1, id_2, new) 
VALUES (1, 1, 1), (1, 3, 1), (1, 4, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE new = 1
```

so i get this table because i didn't update `id_2 = 2` row

```
|  id_1  |  id_2  |  new  |
|  1     |  1     |  1    |
|  1     |  2     |  0    |
|  1     |  3     |  1    |
|  1     |  4     |  1    |
```

---

how can i do this more efficiently and maybe in one query like

```
INSERT INTO table (id_1, id_2, new) 
VALUES (1, 1, 1), (1, 3, 1), (1, 4, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE (new = 0 WHERE id_1 = 1) AND UPDATE (new = 1)
```

Comment: I don't think there is a simple way to do this -- updating rows that are not part of the update.

Comment: You can't do this in a single query. One way or another, you will need two queries - and you current approach looks quite good.

Comment: is it better if i add on the update query this `WHERE id_1 = 1 AND new = 1` or it will not benfit  because of not having index?